# package: cannot download, http://*.com/*/*.git uses insecure protocol

Tags: git, go, go-get

I'm trying to run `go get -u -v` in my application repository, but I'm receiving an error:

```
$ go get -u -v
package */*/*: cannot download, http://*.com/*/*.git uses insecure protocol
```

The self-hosted Git repository runs with `http`, *not* `https`. How to force it to use `http` and forget about `https`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$ go help get` it is mentioned:

```
$ go help get

...

The -insecure flag permits fetching from repositories and resolving
custom domains using insecure schemes such as HTTP. Use with caution.

...
```

Therefore `$ go get -u -v -insecure` resolved the error.